# Creating a fork causing fgets to reread a file infinitly

Tags: c, process, io, fork

I'm trying to write a program that reads through a bunch of unix commands, and creates child processes to execute them. It has one argument that determines the maximum number of child process I want running at one time. I redirect `stdin` to a separate file full of commands like this: `./a.out 3 < batchcmds`. When I run the code, it winds up rereading through all the commands over and over, but when I comment out the switch statement, it runs as expected (except, of course, creating processes and running commands). I've confirmed through testing that all of the child processes terminate before reaching the end of the while loop, so the main process must be getting messed with somehow, causing it to repeat reading through a file. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int makearg(char*, char***);

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        // reads argument
        int maxpc = atoi(argv[1]);
        int pc = 0;

        // read from the file and assign it to a child
        char command[BUFFERSIZE];
        while(fgets(command, 128, stdin) > 0) {
                char** args;
                makearg(command, &args);

                if(pc >= maxpc) {
                        wait(NULL);
                        pc--;
                }

                switch(fork()) {   // When I comment out from here to the comment below it works as expected
                        case 0:
                                // is child
                                execvp(args[0], args);
                                printf("execv failed to run %s", command);
                                exit(0);
                                printf("child is immortal\n");
                                return -1;
                        case -1:
                                printf("failed to create child\n");
                                break;
                        default:
                                // is parent
                                pc++;
                }  // The comment below
                printf("end while loop: %x:%s", getpid(), command);
        }

        // wait for children to finish
        for(; pc > 0; pc--) wait(NULL);

        return 0;
}

int makearg(char* s, char*** args) {
        // count the tokens in the string
        int tokencount = 1;
        int slength = 1;
        for(char* c = s; *c != '\0'; c++) {
                if(*c == ' ')
                        tokencount++;
                slength++;
        }

        // set up the array of tokens
        char** tokens = (char**)malloc(tokencount*sizeof(char*));
        if(tokens == NULL) {
                return -1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < tokencount; i++)
                tokens[i] = (char*)malloc(slength*sizeof(char));
        if(tokens == NULL) {
                for(int i = 0; i < tokencount; i++)
                        free(tokens[i]);
                free(tokens);
                return -1;
        }

        // copy data over to the token array
        int itoken = 0;
        int ichar = 0;
        for(char* c = s; *c != '\0'; c++) {
                if(*c == ' ') {
                        tokens[itoken][ichar] = '\0';
                        itoken++;
                        ichar = 0;
                }
                else if(*c != '\n') {
                        tokens[itoken][ichar] = *c;
                        ichar++;
                }
        }
        tokens[itoken][ichar] = '\0';

        *args = tokens;
        return tokencount;
}
```

This really has me stumped, and I can't find anyone with a similar problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Side note: In the function `makeargs`, you have two lines with the content `if(tokens == NULL) {`. The second one should probably be `if(tokens[i] == NULL) {`, and it should probably be inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Show an exact copy of the input you use. Show the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three problems in your program.

One is the second argument to `execvp` should be a list of pointers terminated by a null pointer, but your `makearg` routine does not construct such a list. Two steps are required to fix this. First, `malloc(tokencount*sizeof(char*));` should be `malloc((tokencount+1)*sizeof(char*));`. Second, near the end of the routine, mark the end of the list with a null pointer: `tokens[tokencount] = 0;`.

Another is that forking will cause duplicated output. This is because C streams are often buffered, meaning functions such as `printf` do not immediately send output to the operating system to be written to a device. Instead, the data is written into a buffer managed by the C stream interface. It is sent to the operating system when the buffer is full or when a new-line character is written (if the stream is *line buffered*.) Streams connected to a terminal are typically line buffered. Streams connected to a pipe are typically fully buffered.

When your program forks, any data put into the buffer by `printf` (or other routines) but not yet sent to the operating system will be duplicated in the child. Eventually, both the parent and the child may send their copy of the data to the operating system, so you will see a message twice. It is possible these duplicated messages lead you to believe the program was doing things multiple times, such as reprocessing the same command. That is not the case. Only the message was duplicated, not the prior work of the program.

One way to fix that is to set the standard output stream not to be buffered, which you can do by executing `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` at the beginning of your program. However, that loses all the benefits of buffering (notably efficiency). Another solution is to execute `fflush(stdout);` immediately before a `fork` call. That will send all pending output to the system, so there will be no data in the buffer to be duplicated.

A third problem is in `fgets(command, 128, stdin) > 0`. The C standard does not define comparing a pointer (returned by `fgets`) to a null pointer constant (`0`) with `>`. You can compare it with `!=`. Also, it is good to use `NULL` to make it clear you are comparing to a null pointer: `fgets(command, 128, stdin) != NULL`.

Comment: No that was not the message that was "accidentally" duplicated. I tracked file pointer with ftell after each fgets and for a input file of 25 characters it ends up at position 29 (simulating a duplication of the end of the input). Sometime it is able to never ends the reading at all, modifying the position after the logical end of line endlessly! Correcting makeargs is sufficient. What I can not explain is why fork have this strange "border" effect ? If you eliminate the exec problem survive. Whatever a bug is a bug.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Re “No that was not the message…”: You have used a pronoun without an antecedent, and I do not know what you mean “that” to refer to. Re “for a input file of 25 characters it ends up at position 29”: Translation of carriage-return and new-line pairs to new-line characters can result in a physical file position different from the C stream logical position. Re “ this strange "border" effect”: I do not know what “border effect” you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in `makearg`. Your arg list must terminate with a `NULL` pointer.
From the manual:

> The `execv()`, `execvp()`, and `execvP()` functions provide an array of
> pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list
> available to the new program.  The first argument, by convention, should point to the file name associated with the file being executed.
> **The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer.**

You can modify it like this:

```
int makearg(char* s, char*** args) {
        // count the tokens in the string
        int tokencount = 1;
        int slength = 1;
        for(char* c = s; *c != '\0'; c++) {
                if(*c == ' ')
                        tokencount++;
                slength++;
        }

        // set up the array of tokens
        char** tokens = (char**)malloc((tokencount+1)*sizeof(char*)); // One more to store NULL pointer
        if(tokens == NULL) {
                return -1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < tokencount; i++) {
                tokens[i] = (char*)malloc(slength*sizeof(char));
                if(tokens[i] == NULL) { // correctly catch malloc problems, here
                    for(int i = 0; i < tokencount; i++)
                        free(tokens[i]);
                    free(tokens);
                    return -1;
                }
        }

        // copy data over to the token array
        int itoken = 0;
        int ichar = 0;
        for(char* c = s; *c != '\0'; c++) {
                if(*c == ' ') {
                        tokens[itoken][ichar] = '\0';
                        itoken++;
                        ichar = 0;
                }
                else if(*c != '\n') {
                        tokens[itoken][ichar] = *c;
                        ichar++;
                }
        }
        tokens[itoken][ichar] = '\0';
        tokens[itoken+1] = NULL; // last is NULL

        *args = tokens;
        return tokencount+1; // returns the right count of args including the NULL
}
```